# How to parse parameters from input field to URI using ajax GET method

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am working with asmx webservice which has a method and that has two parameters 
1, UserTicket 
2, ZipCode. 
I am sending the userTicket encoded but I want the zip code to be provided by the user. My service can only use ajax GET method.

```
<script>
        function callwm() {
            var zipcode = $('#zip').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://services.opisnet.com/RealtimePriceService/RealtimePriceServicePlus.asmx/GetZipCodeResults?UserTicket=0Hv9MEJRuKaun58MzNlhz0H30WlHxQCUB6ZfUa2dS7eVwA4x1QvSmR4Dml/lnfFm",
                data: "&ZipCode=" + encodeURIComponent($('#zip').val()),
                dataType: "xml",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(result);
                    var lnt = "<Station_Name>".length;
                    var ind = xmlString.indexOf("<Station_Name>");
                    var lst = xmlString.indexOf("</Station_Name>");
                    var str = xmlString.substr(ind + lnt, lst - (ind + lnt));
                 $('#res').text('Station Name:  '+str);
 },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('failure');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get list" onclick="callwm();" />
```

Comment: You should use `url: "https://services.opisnet.com/RealtimePriceService/RealtimePriceServicePlus.asmx/GetZipCodeResults?UserTicket=0Hv9MEJRuKaun58MzNlhz0H30WlHxQCUB6ZfUa2dS7eVwA4x1QvSmR4Dml/lnfFm&ZipCode=" + encodeURIComponent($('#zip').val()),` and ignore `data` and `dataType`

Comment: If you pick type GET, you can simply enter the data as objects and they will be automatically converted to query string for the request.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I tried it but its only displaying the html not the xml like its supposed to.. for example. $('#res').text('Station Name:  '+str); in this its only showing 'Station Name:' not str (xml data from service). It was before when I was sending both zipcode and userToken encoded in the url

Comment: My bad.. It actually worked! My userTicket got expired for some reason. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please also tell me how to pass more than one parameter through this method? I am sorry I am just so new to jquery and ajax. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can anybody please help me. I am trying like this.
url:"myurl"+ encodeURIComponent($("#latitude").val() + encodeURIComponent + "&Longitude=" + ($("#longitude").val())),